# trying to merge table with my employees table

Tags: sql, sql-server

so first I did this insert

```
INSERT INTO vDDUP(VPUserName, ShowRates, RestrictedBatches, FullName, Phone, EMail, ConfirmUpdate, DefaultCompany, EnterAsTab, ExtendControls, SavePrinterSettings, SmartCursor, ToolTipHelp, MinimizeUse, AccessibleOnly, MenuAdmin, FormAdmin, MultiFormInstance, HideModFolders, MenuInfo, MergeGridKeys, AltGridRowColors, DefaultDestType, WindowsUserName,PRCo, Employee, MyTimesheetRole, IsHelpUpToDate, ShowLogoPanel, ShowMainToolbar, UserType, SaveLastUsedParameters, ReportViewerOptions, PMErrorCorrectionSubcontracts, PMErrorCorrectionSubcontractCOs, PMErrorCorrectionPurchaseOrders, PMErrorCorrectionPurchaseOrderCOs, AutoLogOutFlag, CSAllowDocEdit, CSSelectAllAttachments, LookupColumnAutoSize, AllowExternalLogin, LoginFailCount, AttachmentListerStyle, ShowUnsavedChangesOnStartup, DisallowSelfSecurityYN, SuppressMaxWarningRows, EnableSharedSearch)
select E.Username, 'N', 'N', E.Employee_FName + ' ' + E.Employee_LName, E.Phone_Number, E.Email, 'N', 1, 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 0, 'N', 'N', 'EMail', 'domain\' + E.Username, 1, E.Employee_ID, 1, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 0, 'N', 0, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 0, 3, 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N'
from [server].[db].[dbo].[Employees] as E
where E.Username = 'user'
```

this worked perfect but then I wanted to grab all users from that employees table and do a merge into my vd table

```
  MERGE vDDUP v
Using( select E.Username
from [server].[db].[dbo].[Employees] E where E.Username is not null ) E
on (E.[Username] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = v.[VPUserName] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
when Matched 
Then update 
set PRCo = 1, 
Employee = E.Employee_ID
When Not Matched By Target
Then Insert
(VPUserName, ShowRates, RestrictedBatches, FullName, Phone, EMail, ConfirmUpdate, DefaultCompany, EnterAsTab, ExtendControls, SavePrinterSettings, SmartCursor, ToolTipHelp, MinimizeUse, AccessibleOnly, MenuAdmin, FormAdmin, MultiFormInstance, HideModFolders, MenuInfo, MergeGridKeys, AltGridRowColors, DefaultDestType, WindowsUserName,PRCo, Employee, MyTimesheetRole, IsHelpUpToDate, ShowLogoPanel, ShowMainToolbar, UserType, SaveLastUsedParameters, ReportViewerOptions, PMErrorCorrectionSubcontracts, PMErrorCorrectionSubcontractCOs, PMErrorCorrectionPurchaseOrders, PMErrorCorrectionPurchaseOrderCOs, AutoLogOutFlag, CSAllowDocEdit, CSSelectAllAttachments, LookupColumnAutoSize, AllowExternalLogin, LoginFailCount, AttachmentListerStyle, ShowUnsavedChangesOnStartup, DisallowSelfSecurityYN, SuppressMaxWarningRows, EnableSharedSearch)
 Values(E.Username, 'N', 'N', E.Employee_FName + ' ' + E.Employee_LName, E.Phone_Number, E.Email, 'N', 1, 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 0, 'N', 'N', 'EMail', 'domain\' + E.Username, 1, E.Employee_ID, 1, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 0, 'N', 0, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 0, 3, 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N');
```

so I would merge all users that had a username into my vd passing in the values I needed to set for them to login.

some reason I am getting a no column name was specified for column 2, 3, 5 of E

says is on line 33 which is where my on statment is.

so the reason for some of this syntax is because employees table is on a diff server and db than the vd table.

Comment: Why do you have all those string literals in the source of your merge? Start by removing them, they are nothing but noise here. Then you need to provide a name for EVERY column in the source. The only one that wouldn't have a name at that point should be EmployeeFullName. Or you could just make that two columns and not bother giving is a name in the source, just combine them in the insert.

Comment: the string litteralls are columns in the vd table that have to be used I see what you are saying remove them from the select but I have to have them in the insert

Comment: I updated it but now it is saying invalid column name email and employeeID

Comment: For your test here, simplify the query, then the error will be easier to see.

Comment: You just removed all of those columns from your initial `MERGE SELECT`, but have included them in your `THEN INSERT`.

Comment: @Shawn I simplfied it up top but for some reason it isn't reconizing my values now of e.username, e.employee_fname all of that

Comment: Well of course not, you removed them from the query. That means the ONLY column now available in E is Username. All the rest of them were removed.

Comment: @Shawn I have to have those they columns that are not null in the vd table that I have to fill out. The string litteralls do not come from the employee table only the user name employee name all of those that I have specified.

Comment: `Using( select E.Username from ...` no longer includes the values you want to `INSERT`.

Comment: Each of those literal columns need to be aliased so they can be `INSERT`ed.

Comment: @shawn thank you so much dude I didn't understand the merge but you clarified it for me thanks dude you are awesome.

Comment: Never mind my last comment. Look down at Sean's answer. Making the query more readable makes it easier to see how the columns are inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something pretty close to what you need. I can't test this as I have table to work with. Also notice how I spread out the columns so you can see them instead of being a wall of text.

```
MERGE vDDUP v
Using
( 
    select E.Username
        , E.Employee_FName
        , E.Employee_LName
        , E.Phone_Number
        , E.Email
        , E.Username
        , E.Employee_ID
    from [server].[db].[dbo].[Employees] E 
    where E.Username is not null 
) E on (E.[Username] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = v.[VPUserName] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
when Matched 
Then update 
    set PRCo = 1
        , Employee = E.Employee_ID
When Not Matched By Target
Then Insert
(
    VPUserName
    , ShowRates
    , RestrictedBatches
    , FullName
    , Phone
    , EMail
    , ConfirmUpdate
    , DefaultCompany
    , EnterAsTab
    , ExtendControls
    , SavePrinterSettings
    , SmartCursor
    , ToolTipHelp
    , MinimizeUse
    , AccessibleOnly
    , MenuAdmin
    , FormAdmin
    , MultiFormInstance
    , HideModFolders
    , MenuInfo
    , MergeGridKeys
    , AltGridRowColors
    , DefaultDestType
    , WindowsUserName
    , PRCo
    , Employee
    , MyTimesheetRole
    , IsHelpUpToDate
    , ShowLogoPanel
    , ShowMainToolbar
    , UserType
    , SaveLastUsedParameters
    , ReportViewerOptions
    , PMErrorCorrectionSubcontracts
    , PMErrorCorrectionSubcontractCOs
    , PMErrorCorrectionPurchaseOrders
    , PMErrorCorrectionPurchaseOrderCOs
    , AutoLogOutFlag
    , CSAllowDocEdit
    , CSSelectAllAttachments
    , LookupColumnAutoSize
    , AllowExternalLogin
    , LoginFailCount
    , AttachmentListerStyle
    , ShowUnsavedChangesOnStartup
    , DisallowSelfSecurityYN
    , SuppressMaxWarningRows
    , EnableSharedSearch
)
Values
(
    E.Username
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , E.Employee_FName + ' ' + E.Employee_LName
    , E.Phone_Number
    , E.Email
    , 'N'
    , 1
    , 'Y'
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , 'Y'
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , 0
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , 'EMail'
    , 'domain\' + E.Username
    , 1
    , E.Employee_ID
    , 1
    , 'Y'
    , 'Y'
    , 'Y'
    , 0
    , 'N'
    , 0
    , 'Y'
    , 'Y'
    , 'Y'
    , 'Y'
    , 'N'
    , 'Y'
    , 'Y'
    , 'Y'
    , 'N'
    , 0
    , 3
    , 'Y'
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
    , 'N'
);
```